# Playwright - sharing state between tests

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm learning Playwright and JavaScript concurrently so this may be an elementary question - I'm wondering how people would recommend sharing state - variable `customerId` in this case - between tests.

Example:

```
test.describe.only('Generate a new customer', () => {
  let customerId
  let baseUrl = process.env.SHOP_URL
  
  test('Create new customer', async ({ request }) => {
    const response = await request.post(baseUrl +    `/shopify/v5/customer`, {})
    
    const responseBody = JSON.parse(await response.text())
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200)
    customerId = responseBody.customerId //need to persist customerId to pass into following test

  })

  test('Update customer details', async ({ request }) => {
     const response = await request.post(baseUrl +    `/shopify/v5/customer/update`, {})
      {
        data: {
          customerId: customerId, //customerId is undefined here
          name: "Fred"
        },
      }
    )
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200)
  })
```

the `customerId` is clearly out of scope in the second test.  I will probably refactor these to use a library such as Axios eventually because I am using the Playwright tests to generate data - I'm not actually testing the api here.  In the meantime I just need `customerId` to be persisted in subsequent api calls.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614296/21881142
This will not work if you have a failed test in between. All data will be lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make your example work you need to run the tests in [serial mode](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-retries#serial-mode), something like this will work:

```js
test.describe.serial('Generate a new customer', () => {
  let customerId
  let baseUrl = process.env.SHOP_URL
  
  test('Create new customer', async ({ request }) => {
    const response = await request.post(baseUrl +    `/shopify/v5/customer`, {})
    
    const responseBody = JSON.parse(await response.text())
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200)
    customerId = responseBody.customerId //need to persist customerId to pass into following test

  })

  test('Update customer details', async ({ request }) => {
     const response = await request.post(baseUrl +    `/shopify/v5/customer/update`, {})
      {
        data: {
          customerId: customerId, //customerId is undefined here
          name: "Fred"
        },
      }
    )
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That is anti-pattern, tests should be independent especially in playwright where tests run in parallel by default:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel

You can merge those two tests into one test.

If You still want to go that way I guess You can use fixtures or hooks to make it work, here are examples:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#without-fixtures

Comment: agreed, thank you - this is only intended as a short term solution while I famliarise with Playwright - ultimately there will be a node library that supports http requests and I will create this as a utility function